# RegEx pick Full word

Tags: regex

If i want to change the below

> Hello

To:

> HELLO

Its fine when i do `\(Hello)\`

But it dosent work for words such as:

> HeLLo hello HellO

Is there any way i can get regex to pick all `hello` characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your regular expression engine, there should be a way to indicate a case insensitive match.

For example, in Perl:

```
/Hello/i
```

or Python:

```
re.compile(r"hello", re.IGNORECASE)
```

Alternatively, you can do it manually for each character:

```
[Hh][Ee][Ll][Ll][Oo]
```

Answer (score 4):

use incasesensitive modifier of your library for instance

```
/hello/i
```

Also it would be wise to add \b, word delimiter so you do not select "ahello".

```
/\bhello\b/i
```